# Qgis standalone script using eclipse IDE -No data provider available issue

Tags: qgis, python, eclipse, qgs

I know, the question is asked few times also in this forum but
i apply already the presented solutions without any chance to fix the problem.

In General the source code looks like the following:

```
from qgis.core import *

# supply path to qgis install location
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:/path/to the/apps/qgis", True)
print QgsApplication.showSettings()

# create a reference to the QgsApplication
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

# load providers
qgs.initQgis()

if len(QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()) == 0:
    raise RuntimeError('No data providers available.')

mylayer = QgsVectorLayer("C:/path to/the actual /layer.shp","DB_tracks", "ogr")
if not mylayer.isValid():
print "Layer failed to load!"
# When your script is complete, call exitQgis() to remove the provider and
# layer registries from memory
qgs.exitQgis()
```

Now the actual issue is the "no data provider available" exception
thrown by the `QgsProviderRegistry`.
By researching  the directory to the providers seems set correct.
The directories are set according
to the respond of `QgsApplication.showSettings()` as shown below:

```
Application state:
QGIS_PREFIX_PATH env var:       
Prefix:     C:/NONBKU/QGIS Essen/apps/qgis
Plugin Path:        C:/NONBKU/QGIS Essen/apps/qgis/plugins
Package Data Path:  C:/NONBKU/QGIS Essen/apps/qgis/.
Active Theme Name:  
Active Theme Path:  /themes\\icons/
Default Theme Path: :/images/themes/default/
SVG Search Paths:   D:/Users/Username
    C:/Path/QGIS Essen/apps/qgis/./svg/
User DB Path:   C:/Path/QGIS Essen/apps/qgis/./resources/qgis.db
```

By calling than `QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList())`
the following exception is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\path\workspace_eclipse\DB_QGIS_Python\src\python_DB_test.py", 
line 18, in <module>
raise RuntimeError('No data providers available.')
RuntimeError: No data providers available.
```

So any ideas which issue forces the `"no data providers available"`
exception?